# Recursively finding files that match an extension, and then returning the a count of those files based on parent directory

Tags: powershell, file, logging, find

I'm very new to powershell, and almost everything is copied from somewhere else, so please bear with me.

Here's what I have so far (It's not working correctly):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\" -Recurse -Filter *.log |
    Split-Path -Parent | 
        %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is find out where *.log files may be in a drive. Since I'm applying this to many hosts at a time, I want a summary of these files.

What I get:

```
D:\Game Files\appdata\BlackCipher\BlackCall.log
D:\Game Files\appdata\BlackCipher\BlackCipher.log
D:\Game Files\appdata\BlackCipher\BlackXchg.log
D:\Game Files\appdata\BlackCipher\NGClient.log
D:\Game Files\Counter-Strike Source\debug.log
D:\Game Files\Games\Furi\2016-07-08_164326\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\bnet_client.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2014-01-06_155616\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2014-02-02_201924\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2014-02-02_201946\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2014-02-02_222450\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2015-06-24_082024\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2015-07-06_174250\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2015-07-25_180738\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2015-10-19_160134\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2016-07-13_164124\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2016-12-19_021056\error.log
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\2017-08-27_132304\error.log
```

What I would like :

```
D:\Game Files\appdata\BlackCipher 4
D:\Game Files\Counter-Strike Source 1
D:\Game Files\Games\Furi\2016-07-08_164326 1
D:\Game Files\Hearthstone\ 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, you just need to use the `Group-Object` function instead of messing with the path and trying to count it manually.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\" -Recurse -Filter *.log | Group-Object -Property Directory -NoElement
```

From there it's easy enough to format however you'd like.

```
... | ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Count }
```